# Efficient manipulation of a list of cartesian coordinates in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, python-2.7, coordinates

#### Background:

I'm writing a program which handles large quantities of data related to the networks of vertices of various regular shapes. I have a working generator which produces a list of cartesian coordinates corresponding to the vertices of said shapes based on a range of user input parameters. The data is then passed to filters which clear up duplicate entries, sort the data and various other functions, from where the cleaned data is fed to a canvas module which loops through and draws the vertices.

#### Question:

I need to implement a new filter that efficiently loops through the coordinates, comparing each pair against every other pair, i.e. `(x1,y1)`->`(x2,y2)` to `(x1,y1)`->`(xn,yn)`, `(x2,y2)`->`(x3,y3)` to `(x2,y2)`->`(xn,yn)` etc. for all entries and, for example, if the relationship between `(x1,y1)` and `(x5,y5)` fits `[(x5-x1)^2+(y5-y1)^2]=vertex_spacing^2`, then the two sets of coordinates are then paired with their respective list entry numbers and appended to a new list where one entry would be of the form: `[(x1,y1), (x5,y5), 0, 4]` for example. What is the most efficient method for achieving this?

#### My Attempts:

I've looked at quite a few methods for handling lists on here and on various guides. I've attempted nested 'for' and 'if' loops, but find while this method can work it leads to excessively long run times, as well as attempting to breaking the problem down into numerous smaller for loops.

#### Further Notes:

The ultimate aim of this is to use the resulting coordinates for front-end interface elements, and to be saved and imported as necessary. The function of the list positions 0 and 4 in `[(x1,y1), (x5,y5), 0, 4]` is to enable the interface to group coordinates for later use in canvas objects. The method should be able to process potentially thousands of coordinates.

Thank you in advance for any help, I am of course willing to improve the phrasing/information I've supplied and/or add example code if it is unclear what I am asking in any way- I'm still quite new to this! :)

Comment: Congratulations on a nicely asked question! The problem is that the naive approach (comparing every pair against all other pairs) results in a quadratic running time. How is the distribution of your points? If they are all in a relatively small space (were small is in the order of `vertex_spacing`), this would be a difficult problem, otherwise you could do some simple optimizations (I will post them as an answer based on the distribution).

Comment: Thank you! :) I noticed that to be the case, and I was aware it would happen although I couldn't think of a way around the issue. The value of vertex_spacing itself is set as default to 60, but as it is user defined it can be theoretically any size. The data is also calculated based on multiples and trig identities using vertex_spacing. In essence, vertex_spacing is the fundamental unit in my data. I hope I understood your meaning, and thank you for your help!

Comment: This is a good question. I was thinking a decision tree would be the way to go and I looked at the wikipedia entry for 'closest pair of points problem' because this seems like an extension of that problem (?) for background and it looks like a good decision tree can get you O (n log n). Is this true in this case? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Comment: "*I have a working generator which produces a list of cartesian coordinates corresponding to the vertices of said shapes based on a range of user input parameters*"   It sounds like you're generating these shapes - is it possible for you to just store the data about which vertices are edge-neighbors?  Rather than calculate it later?  Just a thought.

Comment: @erewok a [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) is probably more useful in a partitioning predicate.

Comment: @Brionius- currently I'm generating data which is then fed to the canvas and drawn. I implemented the method you supplied for a previous question but was advised it wasn't 'what they wanted', in that the data was the priority over the visual elements. Fundamentally, the program is essentially for visualising large quantities of data, and after conferring with the individual that commissioned the program, they were insistent on generating the data first, and then building the visual elements on top. Hope I understood your point, and thanks again for your earlier help! :)

Comment: @Brionius- A further note is that they required a method that allowed  data to be saved and/or to be imported, sorted and visualised again at any point in the program, hence generating the shapes anew for each run did not fulfil their requirements.

Comment: Those who reinvent graphviz are doomed to reinvent graphviz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're basically checking is:

> for each vertex `v`, find all vertices `u` such that `u` is on the circle of radius `vertex_spacing` around `v`.

If the distribution of your points is such that not all points are close together, I think of two approaches to speed up the search:

1. The simplest way to speed up this process would be to sort the points by x-coordinate. That way, you can possible skip many comparisons. As a simple example, assume that the x-coordinates are `[1, 2, 10, 15, 18, 20, 21]` and `vertex_spacing = 5`. You only need to compare the first vertex with the second one, because all the other vertices are obviously outside the circle around the first vertex.

   Note that this approach is useless if all points are close together. In other words, if `vertex_spacing = 25`, you cannot skip any comparison.
2. Along the same lines, you could use a 2-dimensional [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd_tree). This is equivalent to the sorting approach, but in two dimensions. Given a vertex `(x, y)` and `vertex_spacing = v`, you would have to check all points in the range `([x-v, x+v], [y-v, y+v])`. Using the same example as before, assume the first point had coordinates `(1, 0)` and the second one `(2, 10)`, there would be no need to compare the first vertex to anything.

Both approaches are heuristics and do not give any improvements on the worst-case running time (quite contrary: you also have the overhead of the sorting / building the k-d tree), but if the vertices are typically at least `vertex_space` apart, this could speed up your search a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I was too slow to beat Heuster's description of the algorithm, but here's an implementation of the sort-by-x-co-ordinate approach:

```
def pairs(coords, vertex_spacing):
    results = []
    vsquared = vertex_spacing * vertex_spacing
    coords = sorted(coords)
    for ia, (xa, ya) in enumerate(coords):
        for ib, (xb, yb) in enumerate(coords[ia:]):
            dx = xb - xa
            if dx > vertex_spacing:
                break
            dy = yb - ya
            if dx * dx + dy * dy == vsquared:
                results.append([(xa, ya), (xb, yb), ia, ia + ib])
    return results
```

... and here it is in action:

```
>>> coords = list((x, y) for x in range(100) for y in range(100))
>>> p = pairs(coords, 5)
>>> from random import choice
>>> choice(p)
[(93, 36), (96, 40), 9336, 9640]
>>> choice(p)
[(9, 57), (13, 54), 957, 1354]
>>> choice(p)
[(46, 69), (46, 74), 4669, 4674]
```

On my machine, `pairs(coords, 5)` takes 1.5 seconds to check 10,000 co-ordinate pairs (and 0.15 seconds to check 2,500).

**EDIT**: I forgot to add `ia` to `ib` to compensate for enumerating over a slice - fixed now.

Comment: +1 And I wasn't strong enough in Python to write the code ;-)

Comment: I'd started writing something similar as soon as @Heuster had posted, but this appears dead on so I'll copy it wholesale, I'm just going to finish adapting it before I confirm it as answered, but thank you to you both!

Comment: @MarkyD43 Note the fix I just made :-)

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you! I want to mark both as answered, but as @Heuster's answer is a good general solution for anyone with a similar problem I'll accept that. Thank you again!

Comment: Thanks for building the algorithm. My initial thought was to use enumerate in two for-loops in the same fashion in order to compare a point to the *rest* of the points but I couldn't puzzle out how the rest of the algorithm worked. Thanks again for taking the time to write it out.

Answer (score 2):

The slowest parts of your algorithm are the separate handling of the *x* and *y* coordinates and the hypotenuse calculation.   Both of these can be sped-up by using Python's native complex number type:

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> parray = list(starmap(complex, [(5, 1), (8.5, 3), (3.75, 4.25)]))
>>> a = parray[0]
>>> b = parray[1]
>>> a
(5+1j)
>>> b
(8.5+3j)
>>> a-b
(-3.5-2j)
>>> abs(a-b)
4.031128874149275
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to speed things up is to use some kind of spatial index, so that you rule out searching points that are obviously far apart. Here is a module that might be useful: http://toblerity.org/rtree/. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree.