# Optimisation of Nearest Neighbour Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, optimization

**Background:**
Some time ago I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291829/efficient-manipulation-of-a-list-of-cartesian-coordinates-in-python) regarding the most efficient method for finding the neighbours of every point   in a set of data by comparing each point against every other. I've attempted to optimise the process by breaking the coordinate list into separate sets based on their x coordinates, and grouping them in overlapping sets. The neighbour finder 'pairs_3' is then used on each set. This then gives me a full set of connections between vertices. The code below is a snippet of what I have so far:

```
def pairs_3(coordinates, vertex_spacing): #Function from previous question
    i=-1
    results_2 = []
    results_2 [:]= []
    for (xc, yc, zc) in enumerate(coordinates):
        for (xb, yb, zb) in enumerate(coordinates[ic:]):
            dx = xb - xc 
            if sqrt(dx**2) > a:
                    break
            dy = yb - yc
            dz = zb - zc

            if (sqrt(dx**2+dy**2+dz**2)) == vertex_spacing:
                i+=1
                results_2.append([(xc, yc, zc), (xb, yb, zb), width, dx, dy, dz, edge])
    return results_2

Coordinates_xyz=sorted(set(zip(Coord_x,Coord_y,Coord_z))) #Full 3D coordinate list
Coord_x_set=sorted(set(Coord_x))
numerical_width = Coord_x.count(Coord_x_set[1]) #gets number of columns
N=numerical_width
Col_subList = [Coordinates_xyz[n:n+2*N] for n in range(0,         len(Coordinates_xyz), N)] #Col_subList is a list of grouped data according to x coordinate. The data is always discrete, so this is possible.

new_p_2=[]
new_p_2[:]=[]
new_p_3=[]
new_p_3[:]=[]
#where a is vertex separation, a known value used to generate the data
for x in Col_subList:
   new_p_2.append(pairs_3(x, a))

for x in new_p_2:
    for y in x:
        new_p_3.append(y)

p_2=new_p_3
start=column(p_2,0) #Start Vertex
end=column(p_2, 1) #End Vertex
s_i=[] #Start Vertex Index
s_i[:]=[] 
c_i=[] #Connection Index
c_i[:]=[]
for i in start:
indices = [ind for ind, x in enumerate(Coordinates_xyz_final) if x == i]
for j in indices:
    s_i.append(j)

for i in xrange(len(start)):
c_i.append(i)
p_2 = zip(start, end, s_i, c_i) #Final form necessary for later calculations
```

**Question:**
Is there any way to further/better optimise this code? And are there any ways to further break down the problem that aren't more computationally expensive than the function itself?

**Bonus Question:**
Is there a way to efficiently integrate a 'divide and conquer' into the function itself? I.e break the list into sets based on columns inside the function?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rtree).  If you just want it as a tool to solve a problem I suggest you go for one of several existing implementations, Google turns up e.g.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways without optimizing the algo:

1. use **pypy** if you script contains nested for loops or while loop
2. in this case the algo is simple, contains a lot for loops, contains a lot arithmetical operation, then it would be a good idea to write this in C. The simpliest way is to use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html).

also you could use scipy/numpy for math.